# Create rotated rectangle out of an image

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a way to slice an image into pieces like (45deg rotated rectangles).

Here's some code which i found on the internet who has an animation and creates rectangles of an image. 
(version:5)
http://plnkr.co/edit/8tcVPYwEskIRfENGnTd6?p=preview

I tried to create rotated rectangles but the prob is that when i use `transform:rotate(45deg)` out of a piece it first applies the background than rotates it.

**Edit1:** Trying to do sth like creating an div rotated who contains a div who's rotated the other way

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;transform:rotate(45deg)">
 <div class="tilePiece" style="transform:rotate(-45deg);background-image:url('img.jpg');background-position:XX XX"></div>
...
</div>
```

(version:6)
http://plnkr.co/edit/8tcVPYwEskIRfENGnTd6?p=preview

Comment: Looking at your example it looks like the image itself isn't split up, but instead there are a series of empty elements that get their opacity toggled in a random order.

Comment: they aren't empty they get background-image with pos x,y of the original image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it :)
(version 10)
http://plnkr.co/edit/8tcVPYwEskIRfENGnTd6?p=preview

The code is pretty messy but i'll clean up a bit and i'll try other animations.

Answer (score 2):

maybe a hint with CSS using background image and tiles over it .
http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/fAHme/
[image: preview in IE11]

idea is to set a white background to rotated tiles giving each a different delay in transition. In this codepen , i used sass to generate the associate CSS in a loop

```
$n : 24 ;
div:hover span{@for $i from 0 through $n {
  @if $i > 0 {
    &:nth-child(#{$i}) 
  {
    background:white;
    transition: 0s #{$i/3}s;
  }

}
}
}
```

wich gives 24 rules where bth-child is incremented and where transition delay is incremented too .
the firt three looks like this :

```
div:hover span:nth-child(1) {
  background: white;
  transition: 0s 0.33333s;
}
div:hover span:nth-child(2) {
  background: white;
  transition: 0s 0.66667s;
}
div:hover span:nth-child(3) {
  background: white;
  transition: 0s 1s;
} /* and so on untill 24*/
```

To switch from an image to another, then you need to imbricate 2 elements to reverse initial rotation.
you can set transition on both state , so last tiles to fade on hover , will be the first to show on mouse out : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zronD/
[image: 2 images]

you can add a scissor or slide effect http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vtzLe/

Comment: i thought about that at first but the prob is that i wanted to be able to show another image behind it. so that i could use it in a slide show to fade from image to another

Comment: @Marcio then , you need an extra element to rotate backwards and show another background. http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/zronD/

Comment: doesn't look as clean animation as mine but still great job like the idea of a fade/move effect and everything with scss i'll inspect your code later on.

Comment: @Marcio thks, it needs a browser that has memory avalaible . you can , still via CSS , switch couples of image,  http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/jglGd but sure, JS is more solid at this time for this kind of things.